# What causes this "No migration could be found with the version number" error in Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a *Social Network* application with Codeigniter 3, **[Ion-Auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth)** and Bootstrap 4. You can see the **[Github repo HERE](https://github.com/Ajax30/ci-social)**.

I have enabled migrations, then created the migration file `002_add_messages_table.php`:

```
class Migration_Create_Messages_Table extends CI_Migration {

  public function up()
  {
    $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
      'id'=>array(
        'type'=>'INT', 
        'constraint' => 11,
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'auto_increment' => TRUE
      ),

      'from'=>array(
        'type'=>'INT',
        'constraint' => 11,
        'null'       => FALSE
      ),

      'to'=>array(
        'type'=>'INT',
        'constraint' => 11,
        'null'       => FALSE
      ),

      'message'=>array(
        'type'=>'TEXT',
      ),

      'status'=>array(
        'type'=>'TINYINT',
        'constraint' => 1,
      ),

      'created_at'=>array(
        'type'=>'TIMESTAMP',
        'default' => NULL
      ),

    ));
    
    $this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
    $this->dbforge->create_table('messages');
  }

    public function down() {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table('messages');
    }

}
```

I also have a `Migrate.php` controller with this content:

```
<?php defined("BASEPATH") or exit("No direct script access allowed");

class Migrate extends CI_Controller{

    public function index($version){
        $this->load->library("migration");

      if(!$this->migration->version($version)){
          show_error($this->migration->error_string());
      } else {
        echo "Tables created";
      }  
    }
}
```

When I access `http://myapp.com/index.php/migrate/index/002`, instead of creating a `messages` table, the application throws the message:

> No migration could be found with the version number: 002.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034073/no-migration-could-be-found-with-the-version-number-1?

Comment: @Vickel What will happen to the records that already exist in the `users` table?

Comment: @Vickel Also, what URL should I access?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I have tried breaking it and I cannot replicate your error. It just works for me. I get migrations 1 and 2 to work and the migrations table gets updated.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir in regards to your users table, ONLY if you run your 001 migrations table, your groups,users,users_groups and login_attempts tables will be dropped (it's in the migrations file code you have used). Otherwise they will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** UPDATED ***

First off, edit application/config/migration.php and set

```
$config['migration_type'] = 'sequential'; // was 'timestamp' in your repo
```

Secondly, edit your migration file and either change class name to

```
class Migration_Add_Messages_Table extends CI_Migration {
```

or rename the file as 002_create_messages_table
(class name and file name need to be similar)

THEN
If the following query

```
SELECT version FROM migrations
```

is returning anything greater than or equal to 2, what you can do is decrease the version value in your migrations table, and re-run the migration (if it's not on automatic).

Comment: There are no records in my _migrations_ table.

Comment: If you had run this on 1, you should have an entry in your migrations table. In fact you will.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw What URL shall I access?

Comment: I get this messages telling me that some tables already exist. I knew that, I just want to add other tables. How do I skip existing tables?

Comment: You must ask a new question for that. I already answered correctly your original question as I reproduced the solution cloning your repo.